# How was iMessage broken?

Tags: ios, instant-messaging

[It was reported today](https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/national-security/johns-hopkins-researchers-discovered-encryption-flaw-in-apples-imessage/2016/03/20/a323f9a0-eca7-11e5-a6f3-21ccdbc5f74e_story.html) that iMessage was broken ([CVE-2016-1788](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206166)) by a team from John Hopkins around Matthew Green. They said it was kinda to be expected after inspecting the security guide closely enough. The media stories are very vague and [the iOS 9.3 patch notes](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206166) aren't much more concrete either.

**How?**

How could one of the most used and most trusted protocols be broken in such a way that apparently allows attachment recovery for everybody in a privileged man-in-the-middle position (like Apple)? (iOS 9.3 patch notes)

How can the [combination of compressing](https://twitter.com/secparam/status/712003578173505537) (error oracle attack?) and ["only" signing the ciphertext](https://twitter.com/secparam/status/711999852020940800) be leveraged to recover attachments?

Comment: Is this a question or a rant? I see both in there, but it feels like you're asking how to implement an attack.

Comment: @PhilLello I'm genuinely interested in how Apple got their crypto wrong. I already do realize that the attacker needs a very powerful position (such as being Apple) so I won't implement it myself but the details of those attacks are always enlighting.

Answer (score 5):

The flaw with iMessage reference aboved was that it was:

A) Vulnerable to a brute force attack
    This was because of a bug discovered by the researchers that allowed a man-in-the-middle-attack to be setup, due to:

- Strict certificate pinning was not used until iOS 9 -- so an attacker could create an impostor certificate and hack DNS on their local network to be able to start intercepting data and begin the attack.
- No MAC is used in the encrypted payload after receiving an ECDSA signature -- thus, the contents of the message/message integrity is not controlled for.
- The signature can then be tampered with or replaced with another signature.  See image provided by researchers: [image: Attack illustration]
- The "error oracle" compression attack you describe allows one to painstakingly decrypt a message bit-by-bit by taking advantage of how CRC checksums are computed over the original data, but not the AES encrypted payload iMessage then creates.

B) Using a static 64-digit symmetric encryption key for message encryption.

- Rather than use a symmetric key system, an asymmetric system or one utilizing perfect forward secrecy may have been able to prevent this.  Once the man in the middle attack was setup, a brute force attack could be launched until, successfully, retrieving the 64-digit key.

**How?**

Beyond the immediate technical answer, the question as to how this happened is the same for this case as it is for most other commercial, closed-source products; and even many open source packages -- encryption and creating bulletproof cryptosystems is hard.  Even given the most valuable company in the world, Apple, with the best engineers and seemingly unlimited resources; mistakes can be and are made.

For more information, I suggest looking at [Bruce Schneier's article on the subject](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2016/03/imessage_encryp.html), and [the researcher's blog post](http://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/2016/03/attack-of-week-apple-imessage.html) on the subject.